# Divs all over the place when certain button is clicked first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out what is causing my issue. If you go to my site and click the flowers box first, the 3 div images are all over the place. If you hit the back button and then go into vegetables or herbs and then the back button again and then click Flowers again, The divs are organized correctly. What is causing the divs to get shifted all over the place if you click the flowers image first?  Here's the site: http://andrewhnovak.com/Botany/index.html#

Comment: Your alt text is bad. For example `<img width="200" height="200" alt="" src="tomato.jpg">` should be `<img width="200" height="200" alt="Vegetables" src="tomato.jpg">`.

Comment: I fixed that thanks, but that's not causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why but you are dynamically loading a new css page everytime you visit a different page - the flowers page is loading

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="VegetableCss.css" type="text/css">
```

which does not exist, where the other pages are loading

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vegetableCss.css" type="text/css">
```

which does exist, so now that it exists in the head of your html, the flowers page will render properly when you return to it.

But please post your code on the site next time

Comment: That definitely did the trick. I feel dumb for not catching the typo. The dynamically added css file is keeping certain divs from moving from their correct position. Also I have no problem posting my code, but I thought a working demo of the problem would be better. I'll post my code instead next time though. Thanks!